# AngularJS Website looks different on different servers

Tags: css, angularjs, server

It's a problem that's been bugging me for a while and I can't find a solution online.

I have two identical angularJs sites.  They're basically copies of each other.  The only difference is that they are on different servers.

I create a site, it looks great on one server.  I make a copy of it...upload it...on a different server.  It looks drastically different.   The images and text are smaller.  It's as if the screen has been zoomed out by 300%.   Also the Button's are out of place.  On the original server...it was in the middle where I wanted it to be.  On the new one...it's retreated to the bottom left?

The first image is the screenshot of the original site.

[image]

The second Image is the screenshot of the copy site.  As you can see it looks different.

[image]

There's been no css changes and **I'm viewing it on the same browser.**

If it was a different browser...then I could understand the problem.

Does anyone know why?  Thanks.

Comment: could you post the details/version of the software used on both servers? OS/web server/...
also some screenshots/link would be very helpful

Comment: Have you flushed the cache in your browser (css/js are often cached)?  Is the zoom level (domain-specific in Chrome) reset to zero?  (CTRL+0 to reset in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

CTRL F5 did the job!  Thanks everyone.